# Vue.js dont re-render after select element change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

using Vue.js.

I have two object arrays, `category` and `categoryPar`, `category` contains name and parent's name, `categoryPar` contains just name. I want to display only categories that belongs to selected parent. Trying to do it like this:

```
<select v-model="editing.categoryPar"">
       <option v-for="cat in categoryPar" v-bind:value="cat.name">{{ cat.description }}</option>
</select>
<select v-model="editing.category">
       <option v-for="cat in category" v-if="editing.categoryPar == cat.par_name" v-bind:value="cat.name">{{ cat.description }}</option>
</select>
```

Condition is fulfilled but not re-rendered. When I use in console vue.$forceUpdate(); then it works, till I change parent select.

Thank you for help.

Comment: can you create a fiddle? at a glance, I see no issues with your vode

Comment: What if you use `v-show="editing.categoryPar === cat.par_name"` instead of `v-if`  ?

Comment: @Stephen nope, still same, works just after forcing re-render manually with vue.$forceUpdate();

Comment: @samayo as I told, code has no error inside, when i force re-render manually it works, but it does not re-render after changing select element

Comment: You have to use v-for for this to work. Because you are assigning an object/array to v-model. v-model should be given a variable or object property

Comment: @samayo wow it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Make sure to provide a string like `A` to `selectedCategory:  ''` if you don't want the initial dropdown to be empty

Comment: Yes, this I know :) so globally when I bind v-model to object property it will not re-render and it has to be simple variable?

Comment: Yeah, either give is a simple variable or object property that contains a scalar value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a variable of your selected model first.

Currently you are giving your `v-model` an object, which is why it is not working

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      selectedCategory:  '', 
      category: [{name: 'A', parent: 'Alpha'}, {name: 'B', parent: 'Bravo'}, {name: 'C', parent: 'Charlie'}],
      categoryPar: [{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

  <pre>Selected Cat: {{selectedCategory}}</pre>

  <select name="" id="" v-model='selectedCategory'>
    <option :value="cat.name" v-for="cat in category"> {{ cat.name }}</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="" v-for="cat in categoryPar" v-if="cat.name === selectedCategory"> {{ cat.name }}</option>
  </select>

</div>
```